# Documentation: editing a proposed change drops associated comments

Tags: bug, documentation

Editing a proposed change removes any comments that had been made to it.

It would be nice if edits could be made to a proposed change without losing the comment discussion that prompted the edits.

Comment: There's a trick: add a new one and see what happens.

Comment: I did add new comments, and it just shows all the new comments since the edit.

Comment: @Brendan The previous comments should show up after making a new comment, it appears to be a bit glitchy at the moment.  If they don't, try giving it a bit of time, then refreshing the page?